# How to filter a nested array in mongoose in a findOne without the nested object being required

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection called elections and in the elections schema there's a nested array called votes. I'm trying to query an election by id as well as filter the nested votes objects by a `userId` property. I want the parent election object to always be returned and if the current user hasn't voted in the election the `votes` property should be an empty array.

This is my query:

```js
Election.findOne({
    _id: electionId,
    'votes.userId': userId
})
.exec()
```

The issue is that if there aren't any votes with the `userId` the parent Election object isn't returned as well. Is there any way to filter the `votes` property but also make it not-required for matching the parent election object.

I come from a background in sql and in the Sequelize here is how I'd do what I want to do:

```js
models.Election.findOne({
    where: {
        id: electionId
    }
    include: {
        model: models.Vote,
        where: {
            userId
        },
        required: false
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB has a [`$filter` aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)

```
const res = await Election.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(electionId) } },
  { $project: {
      _id: 1,
      votes: { $filter: {
        input: '$votes',
        as: 'userVote',
        cond: { $eq: [ '$$userVote', userId ] },
      }}
  }}
])
```

Which equates to a plain js filter like

```
votes.filter(userVote => userVote.userId === userId)
```

Some other answers to this [question on filtering arrays in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection) are relevant too but the query requirement there is slightly different to your question, more like your initial attempt.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!